# Regex split string to char but with maximum size

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

i am trying to build an regex in C# to match my scanned Barcodes to Groups (GS1 codes).
So every field has an regex to cut the stream, but an FNC1 char is i.e. the end of a field and 1 to 30 Digits before are the value but the first 2 Digits are the application identifier.

Simple Example:

```
var value = "9212345678\u00053302123456";
var regex = "((?<Field>([\d]{2}))(?<Value>(\d{1,30}$)).*?)(?<FNC1>[\x00-\x1f\x80-\xFF])";

Result:
Field -> 92
Value -> 12345678
FNC1 -> (char) 5
```

But when the size of the value is more than 30 Digits, it still matches, but not to the FNC1 divider.
I tryed to use positive lookahead, but then it just turn around an matches 30 Digits from the end of the Value Group.

Could anybody give me the direction i should look for?

Edit:
To clarify it:
The Field is the first 2 Digits in my string, then i have 1 to 30 Digits terminated with an FNC1 sign (here char 5, or anything not normal you could say). If the Value String is 33 Digits, it should not match the Value in the Regex.

So this one should not match:

```
var value = "921234567890123456789012345678901\u00053302123456";
```

And the Value behind the FNC1 divider is following codes, in this example it is "3302123456". That would be a real life example from an scan.

Comment: Try [`@"^(?<Field>\d{2})(?<Value>\d+)(?<FNC1>[\x00-\x1f\x80-\xFF])"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3cField%3e%5cd%7b2%7d%29%28%3f%3cValue%3e%5cd%2b%29%28%3f%3cFNC1%3e%5b%5cx00-%5cx1f%5cx80-%5cxFF%5d%29&i=9212345678%053302123456)

Comment: Please clarify the requirements. `Field` is two digits at the start of the string, right? Then, any 1+ digits  up to some delimiter you call `FNC1`, right? And the FNC1 pattern is `[\x00-\x1f\x80-\xFF]`? Then the suggestion above will work.

Comment: Oh ok, forgot to mention the Basics in my question, sorry. Field should be 2 Digits, Value is between the FNC1 Pattern you already know but could between 1 and 30 Digits, thats why i used the {1,30}, but it reads mehr than it should.

Comment: Then [`^(?<Field>\d{2})(?<Value>\d{1,30})(?<FNC1>[\x00-\x1f\x80-\xFF])`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3cField%3e%5cd%7b2%7d%29%28%3f%3cValue%3e%5cd%7b1%2c30%7d%29%28%3f%3cFNC1%3e%5b%5cx00-%5cx1f%5cx80-%5cxFF%5d%29&i=9212345678%053302123456%0d%0a921234567890123456789012345678901%053302123456&o=m) is what you need.

Comment: Hm no, i still matches with the Input 921234567890123456789012345678901<5> the field 92, value 123456789012345678901234567890 and the fnc1, but i should not match entirely

Comment: See http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3cField%3e%5cd%7b2%7d%29%28%3f%3cValue%3e%5cd%7b1%2c30%7d%29%28%3f%3cFNC1%3e%5b%5cx00-%5cx1f%5cx80-%5cxFF%5d%29&i=9212345678%053302123456%0d%0a921234567890123456789012345678901%053302123456&o=m

Comment: Does that work as expected? Do your matches appear at the start of the string? If not, replace `^` with `\b`. Or remove.

Comment: Hey, yes the unit test is working with your version. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?<Field>\d{2})(?<Value>\d{1,30})(?<FNC1>[\x00-\x1f\x80-\xFF])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3CField%3E%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%28%3F%3CValue%3E%5Cd%7B1%2C30%7D%29%28%3F%3CFNC1%3E%5B%5Cx00-%5Cx1f%5Cx80-%5CxFF%5D%29&i=9212345678%053302123456%0D%0A921234567890123456789012345678901%053302123456&o=m)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<Field>\d{2})` - Capturing group "Field": two digits
- `(?<Value>\d{1,30})` - Capturing group "Value": one to thirty digits
- `(?<FNC1>[\x00-\x1f\x80-\xFF])` - Capturing group "FNC1": a char from the specified ranges in the character class.